# Looking for Special Characters php

Tags: php, string, special-characters

I'm trying to look for special characters within a string. These are vowels with diacritical accents in Spanish. The program is supposed to count the vowels in a string with diacritical accents or not. In Spanish they are á é, í, ó and ú. I'm just lloking for the first 4 though. The problem is that my code doesn't detect the special characters

```
<?php
$string='maría';

$vocales = preg_match_all('/[aeiouáéíó]/i',$string,$matchesV);
echo "<br>vocales = $vocales";

if ((in_array('á',$matchesV))||(in_array('é',$matchesV)) || (in_array('í',$matchesV)) || (in_array('ó',$matchesV))){
    $v = $vocales - 1;
    echo "<br>v $v";
    echo '<br>1'; }

?>
```

Comment: you should use http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php

Comment: Just a tip: You can use `in_array` with two arrays - `if (in_array(array('á','é','í', 'ó'),$matchesV)){`

Answer (score 0):

Why Regular Expressions? If I understood your problem correctly, then it's done with a little change to [this function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php#74952):

```
<?php
function substr_count_array($string, $arr)
{
     foreach ($arr as $letter)
          $count[$letter] += substr_count($string, $letter);
     return $count;
}

$str = 'óóómaóríaéé';
print_r(substr_count_array($str, array("á","é","í","ó")));
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [á] => 0
    [é] => 2
    [í] => 1
    [ó] => 4
)
```